# Javascript not sending id in query string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, radgrid

I have a JavaScript function to passing a query string and when I get to the page that its being redirected to, but when I step through the code the id is not being passed.

the JavaScript is

```
function OpenRadWindow(sender, eventArgs) {
                window.radopen("BankStatements_Update.aspx?id=" + eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("id"), "RadWindow1");
}
```

the code for the page to receive the query string is

```
string a = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```

however if I use the selected change event then I can get the id using this in the code behind..

```
string a = (RadGrid2.SelectedItems[0] as GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString();
```

this works fine, however I have been looking around for awhile now and can't find a way to open radwindow from the code behind.

I have tried using this script to call the javascript function to open the radwindow..

```
string script = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Sys.Application.add_load(OpenRadWindow);</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showWindow", script);
```

but it wouldn't fire.
So I am left to using the original script that I showed and I have no idea why I'm not getting the id.

Answer (score 0):

window.radopen is framework method ? maybe is window.open?

ref http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

or you can do that in your javascript function

```
function OpenRadWindow(sender, eventArgs) { console.log(eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("id"));}
```

And use browser console check your value